# Download a series of Google Docs (.csv files) to my site using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, google-apps, google-apps-script

My conundrum is as follows. I have a lot of data stored in various spreadsheets on Google Docs. Compiling all of the data into a single spreadsheet (for analysis purposes) hit the size limit. Seeing as that is out, I needed another method.

I wrote an Apps Script to take the data and export it all to a series of corresponding .csv files. I now need to get the data from those 30 .csv files stored in Google Docs and import it into a MySQL server. Is this the most efficient method?

Right now, I need a way to import all .csv files from my Google Docs List to the server, where my PHP script can import them to the database. Can you point me in the right direction?

I discovered the following post during my research, which seems pretty close, but it's unfortunately way above my head when it comes to adapting it to my purposes...

http://gdatatips.blogspot.com/2009/07/download-google-doc-using-php-library.html

```
function download($client, $url, $format=null) {
  $sessionToken = $client->getHttpClient()->getAuthSubToken();
  $opts = array(
    'http' => array(
      'method' => 'GET',
      'header' => "GData-Version: 3.0\r\n".
                  "Authorization: AuthSub token=\"$sessionToken\"\r\n"
    )
  );
  if ($url != null) {
    $url =  $url . "&exportFormat=$format";
  }
  return file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($opts));
}

// TODO 1: setup a Zend_Gdata_Docs client in $docs_client
// TODO 2: fetch a $feed or $entry
$contentLink = $feed->entries[0]->content->getSrc();
$fileContents = download($docs_client, $contentLink, 'txt');
echo 'Contents of document "' . $feed->entries[0]->title . '":<hr>';
echo "<pre>$fileContents</pre>";
```

Thanks very much! Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you considered downloading the 30CSV files to your server and doing a simple LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?

Comment: Hi @Edgar, thanks for the comment! Unfortunately this is part of a system that tracks timesheet data, where each of the 30 represents a different person - with constantly updated data. We would ideally like an automatic method to download the csv files, say once per day; In order to ensure the newest information is available. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would download the .csv files using a batch file that is kicked off from scheduled tasks -(i.e. once per day) - then in the batch file kick off SQL  c:\sql\update_timekeeping.sql
The SQl commands stored in the update_timekeeping.sql text file.  Also provides history of running the timekeeping update....

Comment: Thanks @Gator! That looks like what we're going to be doing. Setting up a job to download/upload the files on our local machines. Thanks for the advice everybody!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that `file_get_contents()` should be similar to the PHP version of this script

```
function file_get_contents(){
  //This function generates a pdf of your current spreadsheet and emails it to yourself as attachment
  //Make sure your spreadsheet is not too big. The pdf size tends to be 200kb/page and if too large
  //if the pdf is too large the urlFetch might timeout

  var AUTH_TOKEN = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //Enter your AUTH_TOKEN
  //You can receive it from https://appscripts.appspot.com/getAuthToken

  var ssID=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()+"&gid="+SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  var url = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key="
      + ssID + "&exportFormat=csv"; 
  //Add &gid=x at the end of above url if you only want a particular sheet
  //gid of a sheet can be obtained by the undocumented function getSheetId()
  //ex: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  //exportFormat=xls did not work when I tried. I dont know why

  var auth = "AuthSub token=\"" + AUTH_TOKEN + "\"";

  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: {Authorization: auth}});
  var content=res.getContentText();
  return content
}
```